# how to redirect questions to other SE sites?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Every so often I come across question that I want to flag as "more appropriate at another SE site", but the only option is our "meta". What can we do to get things changed so that we can tag questions for a different SE site, like Stack Overflow for generic programming questions?

Answer (score 0):

You can Flag the question and then choose "Needs Improvement" from the option list, which will allow you to suggest a different SE site.